# How to configure SNS to trigger mail when IP gets blacklisted in AWS WAF?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sns, amazon-waf

I have setup WAF for AWS Application Load balancer. Some times Client IP gets black listed. Every time client asked us to clear IP in WAF rules. So I have plan to configure SNS topic to trigger mail alerts when IP gets black listed in WAF. Is this possible to configure SNS alerts for WAF rules?

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=aws+waf+sns) lead me to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/monitoring_automated_manual.html) and [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/get-started-fms-shield-cloudwatch.html).  What did you search for?